# Highchart won't resize with Gridstack

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gridstack

I have recreated the issue within this CodePen:

https://codepen.io/GeorgeBT97/pen/BxKdEW

As you can see, if you resize the Gridstack tile, the Highchart does not resize with it despite being set to 100% of the height and width of its parent div.

I have seen this thread:

https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/issues/792

Which says using this approach should solve the issue:

```
hChart.setSize(container.width, container.height, false);
```

However, I don't know how or where to implement this to fix the issue. If anybody could explain it would be greatly appreciated. On a side note, despite the fact that Highchart container by default is set to 100% height and width of its parent div, you can clearly see in the CodePen that it is not the full height of the div - Can anyone explain why this is?

Many thanks,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last comment in the github issue that you referred in your question reveals the solution. Use `Chart.reflow` function to adjust the chart to its container. The answer why it has to be done manually comes from the API:

> By default, the chart reflows automatically to its container following
>   a `window.resize` event, as per the `chart.reflow` option. However, there
>   are no reliable events for div resize, so if the container is resized
>   without a window resize event, this must be called explicitly.

**Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow

JS code that does the job:

```
$('.grid-stack').on('gsresizestop', function(event, elem) {
    chart.reflow();
});
```

**Live demo:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vxjaze

Also you incorrectly reffered the container in your CSS . It should be done by **id** (not by class).

Answer (score 1):

I put together a blog post along with code in a github repo for just this:

https://dylandreams.com/2017/05/06/of-charts-and-dashboards/